# How can I arrange the X axis sorted by Y on my plot?

Tags: r, dplyr, plotly

I need to plot on X (the application used ("facebook" ,"tweeter" ... ) ) and the time spend on it on Y axis *but* I have to order the X axis by the Y axis.
How could I do this?

I have tried the following:

```
data_df <- Original_dataFrame%>%                                           

dplyr::select(Applications,Time_Spend) %>%
dplyr::group_by(Applications,Time_Spend)%>%
arrange(Applications,Time_Spend)


plot_ly(data_df, y=~Time_Spend,x = ~Applications, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')
```

Comment: have the answers you have gotten been helpful? If any solved your problem consider accepting one as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach with base R graphics and syntax (no magrittr piping or plot_ly here):

Suppose you have applications `x` and time_spend `y`.

First, create some example data:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- letters[1:10]
y <- sample(101:200, 10)

#   x   y
#1  a 129
#2  b 179
#3  c 141
#4  d 186
#5  e 191
#6  f 105
#7  g 150
#8  h 183
#9  i 151
#10 j 142
```

Next, plot the time_spend (`y`) in increasing order. I'll do this with equally-horizontally-spaced points by letting the x argument be `x=seq_along(y)`.  I'll also omit the labeling of the x axis with `xaxt="n"`:

```
plot(x=seq_along(y), y=sort(y), xaxt="n", xlab="x", ylab="y")
```

Now, I'll add back the labeling along the x axis so that the labels match the plotted data:

```
axis(side=1, at=seq_along(y), labels=x[order(y)])
```

[image: plot]

Comment: i wish i could have it by using plot_ly() in this case

Answer (score 0):

If you want the plot rendered by plotly.

1. Put your data in a tibble or data.frame
2. plot using ggplot ( order x by `reorder()`)
3. render with plotly using `ggplotly` to transform ggplot object

code

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
set.seed(123)
x <- letters[1:10]
y <- sample(101:200, 10)

df <-tibble(x = x, y = y)


g<- ggplot(df, aes(x=reorder(x, y , mean), y =y )) + geom_point()
ggplotly(g)
```